# Use indexedDB instead of webSQL in Chrome not working anymore

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb, pouchdb, web-sql

I use PouchDB to store data in a localDB and then on a remote CouchDB. From now on PouchDB used only indexedDB for the localDB in Chrome but it now use webSQL (in v. 56). I don't encounter this problem with Chrome Canary or Firefox where PouchDB use indexedDB as expected.

I use this code to see if indexedDB or webSQL is used:

```
var pouch = new PouchDB('myDB');
console.log(pouch.adapter);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the adapter manually like `new PouchDB('myDB', {adapter: 'idb'});`? See the [adapters doc](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html).

Comment: It returns `Uncaught Error: Invalid Adapter: idb
    at new Oe (pouchdb-6.1.1.min.js:8)`(only in Chrome 56).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
PouchDB.adapters
```

in the console of your site. It should come up with an object with all adapters that are available.

also, you can type `PouchDB.preferredAdapters` in the console to see if it shows up there. If it shows up as 'idb' it is usable (which it should), then you should be able to just use `new PouchDB('name', {adapter: 'idb'});`.

Comment: Seems that `idb` is not available. `PouchDB.adapters` output `websql`, `http` and `https`. `PouchDB.preferredAdapters` output `websql`.

Comment: thats so weird. Try reinstalling chrome to the latest recommended version

Comment: Oh my mistake! I mixed up two problems... Actually `PouchDB.adapters` show idb in Chrome. I observed that on Chrome iOS (because idb is not available)... On chrome 56 creating a new DB gives me this message: `PouchDB is downgrading "myDB" to WebSQL to avoid data loss, because it was already opened with WebSQL.` And I can't use `new PouchDB('name', {adapter: 'idb'});` because the code is also used on iOS where idb gives an error.